# Problems parsing parameters from Angular post in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, angular-http

I have an Angular.js app that sends a `POST` request to a Rails server endpoint and I'm having trouble passing and reading the parameters.

This is how I send the data

```
$scope.submitForm = function(info) {

    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: app.apiServerUrl + '/complaints/create',
      data: info,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
     // or server returns response with an error status.

  });
};
```

The `info` object passed is a object in the form: `{ title: "something", ocurrence_place: "something" }`.

And in my controller `create` action I have this:

```
def create
  p params
  p params[:title]
end
```

but this is what gets printed in the logs

```
{"{\"title\":\"foo\",\"ocurrence_place\":\"bar\"}"=>nil, "controller"=>"complaints", "action"=>"create"}
nil
```

So, as you can see, I can't access `params` hash attributes. How can I fix this so the controller in my controllers works and prints what is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your info object isn't really an object but a string of JSON.

Try changing `data: info` to `data: JSON.parse(info)` or correcting whatever is calling `submitForm(info)` so that the info argument is really a object.

Comment: thanks, I ended up actually using `JSON.stringify`, but you gave me the first idea :D

Comment: I believe the fix is to change `data: info,` into `data: JSON.stringify(info),`